# Is @ModelAtribute optional in Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, model

I'm learning about Spring framework and I want to know if @ModelAttribute is  an optional annotation? I ask that because I have this code and I thought that I need to use @ModelAttribute if I want to bind a method parameter with an object from a JSP form. But in this example there is no @ModelAttribute.

The JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Complete Reservation</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Complete Reservation</h2>
Airline: ${flight.operatingAirlines}<br/>
Departure City: ${flight.departureCity}<br/>
Arrival City: ${flight.arrivalCity}<br/>

<form action="completeReservation" method="post"/>
<pre>
<h2>Passenger Details:</h2>
First Name:<input type="text" name="passengerFirstName"/>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="passengerLastName"/>
Email:<input type="text" name="passengerEmail"/>
Phone:<input type="text" name="passengerPhone"/>

<h2>Card Details:</h2>
Name on the card:<input type="text" name="nameOnTheCard"/>
Card No:<input type="text" name="cardNumber"/>
Expiry Date:<input type="text" name="expirationDate"/>
Three Digit Sec Code:<input type="text" name="securityCode"/>

<input type="hidden" name="flightId" value="${flight.id}"/>
<input type="submit" value="confirm"/>
</pre>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
@PostMapping("/completeReservation")
public String completeReservation(ReservationRequest request, ModelMap modelMap) {

    Reservation reservation = reservationService.bookFlight(request);
    modelMap.addAttribute("msg", "Reservation created successfully and the id is " + reservation.getId());

    return "reservationConfirmation";
}
```

So how does Spring know to bind the object from the form with the method parameter ReservationRequest request? There is no @ModelAttribute in the controller. Thank you!

Comment: Although it will bind the object itself won't be available as model attribute incase of for instance errors. Next to that it is also part of your methods documentation that you want to use somethiing as a model attribute.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods *Note that use of `@ModelAttribute` is optional (for example, to set its attributes). See “Any other argument” at the end of this table........If a method argument is not matched to any of the earlier values in this table and it is a simple type (as determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty, it is a resolved as a `@RequestParam`. **Otherwise, it is resolved as a `@ModelAttribute`**.*